# Exclude a host from the proxy in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I need to tell IntelliJ NOT to use the HTTP Proxy for certain hosts that reside on our intranet. For some reason, when IntelliJ uses a proxy the Weblogic deployment plugin has issues. This appears to be similar to [this post](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/430612). However, I still need the proxy for other plugins/features.

Most things that use a proxy have some way of excluding hosts. What about IDEA? I am evaluating version 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to the [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html):

```
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|host.mydomain.com"
```

In IntelliJ IDEA this option can be added in **IDEA\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions** (or **IDEA\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions**) on Windows, **IDEA/bin/idea.vmoptions** (or **IDEA/bin/idea64.vmoptions**) on Linux or [Info.plist](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-197) on Mac.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work *BUT* since it's not part of the built-in settings we can't export it and thus we would have to wrap the IDEA install to make this change a company default (or give every dev a link to this SO answer).

Comment: We have an open issue for this problem: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-22044

Comment: shouldn't that be "nonProxyHosts" instead of "noProxyHosts" as per your link?

Comment: Thanks, fixed, but you can find the same typo at that link.